# An exercise in A Course in Finite Group Representation Theory by Peter Webb

Tags: representation-theory

Let $g$ be any non-identity element of a group $G$. How do you show that $G$ has an irreducible complex representation whose character $χ$ satisfies that the real part of $χ(g)$ is negative?

This question is from the book *A Course in Finite Group Representation Theory by Peter Webb*, Chap 3 Exercises 3. Any hint is appreciated.

That's what I have tried: let $χ_1,χ_2,...,χ_r$ be all irreducible complex representations of G. If we can prove that there is some $χ_i(g)$ having non-zero real part, then by Corollary 3.3.7. in that book the statement is clear.

[This is the pdf of that book](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~webb/RepBook/RepBookLatex.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For the benefit of users who don't have a copy of the book, could you please tell us what Corollary 3.3.7 says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g\in G$, with $g\ne e$. By orthogonality of the character table
$$0=\sum_\chi\chi(g)\overline{\chi(e)}$$
where the summation is over the irreducible characters.
Now $\chi(e)=d_\chi$, the dimension of $\chi$ so that
$$0=\sum_\chi d_\chi\chi(g).\tag{1}$$
The term corresponding to the trivial character in (1) is positive.
Therefore there must be a term in (1) with negative real part.

Comment: Oh! The trivial character. I missed it and got stuck for hours. Thanks for your help.